# Mounting a logical volume on a non-empty directory

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, directory

What will happen when you mount a device on a non-empty directory?

Answer (score 2):

The data will be covered by the new mount point, but once unmounted it will appear again. There is no risk of losing them in any way ;)

Comment: Yes when you unmount, you will see the files again. As an aside there are some mount tricks to mount this hidden directory somewhere else (bind mount).